# Error on import of mp4 file with Jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, react-native, mp4, jestjs

In my react-native project, I use react-native-video to play mp4 files. Everything works fine, except that I get an error when I run my unit tests with Jest.

It raises this error when I import the mp4 file: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`. I suppose that there is a special character in the file and that the JavaScript interpreter doesn't like it.

I want to make sure that my video player works. Is there a way to test the player without having this error on the import?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to mock this file, in your jest settings ([docs](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/webpack.html#handling-static-assets))

```
{
  "jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.mp4$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
    }
  }
}
```

`__mocks__/fileMock.js`:

```
module.exports = 'test-file-stub';
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't get the error anymore. But still, react-native-video expect to receive a constant number. Do you know how I could test this component?